# Kinect calibration "Unknown OpenCV format yuv422"

Tags: calibration, kinect, opencv, asus-xtion-pro-live, asus-xtion-pro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to intrinsically calibrate my asus sensor. Therefore I used the ["openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration"](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration?action=show&redirect=openni_camera%2Fcalibration) page. I calibrated the IR without problems. Now I want to calibrate the RGB sensor but get the following error message.

```
Unknown OpenCV format yuv422
```

I use following command (nothing special therefore I dont think that it is a false usage from my side)

```
$rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw camera:=/camera/rgb --size 8x6 --square 0.025
```

My machine is a fresh install Ubunutu 12.4 and ROS Fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51091/kinect-calibration-%22unknown-opencv-format-yuv422%22/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use the image_mono stream instead:

```
$rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono camera:=/camera/rgb --size 8x6 --square 0.025
```

---

Originally posted by [clemens](https://answers.ros.org/users/2191/clemens/) with karma: 71 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-03-14**:
This is the correct answer for camera calibration since it's just going to convert it into mono anyway.  For other applications, you can subscribe to a more compatible image stream on /camera/rgb/image_color